# After removing background and border of a button, focus doesn't show when navigating to it using keyboard in Firefox. (Accessibility)

Tags: html, css, firefox, focus, accessibility

I have a button that is accessible and you can focus on it using keyboard. However after I removed the border and background of the button, when you navigate to it using keyboard the focus doesn't show even though it is on the button. This issue only happens in Firefox. Chrome and IE are fine.

This is my HTML:

```
             <div class="collapse-state-toggle">
                <button class="collapse-state-button" 
                    @click="collapseStateToggle"
                    :aria-expanded="isCollapsed ? 'false' : 'true'" 
                    aria-controls="collapsed-content">
                ...
```

And this is my CSS:

```
    .collapse-state-toggle {
      cursor: pointer;
      float: right;
      user-select: none;

      .collapse-state-button {
        border: none;
        background: none;

        .toggle-text {
```

Comment: So add a focus rule

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WCAG: Firefox and Edge don't show outline on focussed input elements when styles are applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51674380/wcag-firefox-and-edge-dont-show-outline-on-focussed-input-elements-when-styles)

Answer (score 0):

Added these to my code and now it works:

```
<div class="collapse-state-toggle" v-if="items.length > 0">
            <button class="collapse-state-button focus-only" 
                    @click="collapseStateToggle"
                    :aria-expanded="isCollapsed ? 'false' : 'true'" 
                    aria-controls="collapsed-content">
             ...
```

```
    .focus-only:focus {
      outline: 2px solid #1195ff;
    }

    .collapse-state-toggle {
      cursor: pointer;
      float: right;
      user-select: none;
```